# How do I add images in my questions database in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android

I'm building my quiz app for Android in Android Studio. I have got the questions ready, but now I need to add certain images in the relevant questions in the database. For example, an image is only for Question 1, another image for Question 2, and etc.

Here is the FlagDatabase.java code:

```
package com.example.darel.geogame;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class FlagDatabase extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "geo_flag";
    // tasks table name
    private static final String TABLE_QUEST = "quest";
    // tasks Table Columns names
    private static final String KEY_ID = "qid";
    private static final String KEY_QUES = "question";
    private static final String KEY_ANSWER = "answer"; // correct option
    private static final String KEY_OPTA = "opta"; // option A
    private static final String KEY_OPTB = "optb"; // option B
    private static final String KEY_OPTC = "optc"; // option C
    private static final String KEY_OPTD = "optd"; // option D

    private int currImage = 0;

    private SQLiteDatabase dbase;
    public FlagDatabase(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
    @Override

    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        dbase = db;
        String sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_QUEST + " ( "
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_QUES
                + " TEXT, " + KEY_ANSWER + " TEXT, " + KEY_OPTA + " TEXT, "
                + KEY_OPTB + " TEXT, " + KEY_OPTC + " TEXT, " + KEY_OPTD + " TEXT)";
        db.execSQL(sql);
        addQuestion();
// db.close();
    }
    private void addQuestion() {

        Question q1 = new Question("How many colours are there on the flag of Pahang?", "3", "2", "4", "1", "2");
        this.addQuestion(q1);
        Question q2 = new Question("The previous flag of Sarawak looked remarkably similar and inverted to the current flag of which European country?", "Czech Republic", "Austria", "Hungary", "Slovenia", "Czech Republic");
        this.addQuestion(q2);
        Question q3 = new Question("Which of the following state flags does NOT have the colour white?", "Selangor", "Perlis", "Johor", "Melaka", "Perlis");
        this.addQuestion(q3);
        Question q4 = new Question("What feature makes the flag of Sabah unique from the other states' flags?", "14-pointed star", "A sun with 9 rays", "The word SABAH", "Mountain", "Mountain");
        this.addQuestion(q4);
        Question q5 = new Question("Which of the following state flags has the colour blue?", "Penang", "Perak", "Kedah", "Sarawak", "Penang");
        this.addQuestion(q5);
        Question q6 = new Question("The new flag of the Federal Territories of Malaysia was adopted in which year?", "1999", "2003", "2006", "2007", "2006");
        this.addQuestion(q6);
        Question q7 = new Question("The flag of Negeri Sembilan has three colours. Which of the following colours is NOT included?", "Red", "Yellow", "White", "Black", "White");
        this.addQuestion(q7);
        Question q8 = new Question("The flag of Penang was adopted in which year?", "1936", "1957", "1943", "1949", "1949");
        this.addQuestion(q8);
        Question q9 = new Question("Kelantan has one of the most unique flags in Malaysia. What object is NOT featured in the flag?", "Keris", "Spears", "Star", "Shield", "Shield");
        this.addQuestion(q9);
        Question q10 = new Question("What does the yellow colour symbolize in the flag of Sarawak?", "Harmony", "Southeast Asian royalty", "Eastern culture", "The Sun's rays", "Southeast Asian royalty");
        this.addQuestion(q10);
        Question q11 = new Question("Arrange the colours seen on the flag of Perak from top to bottom.", "White, Black, Yellow", "Yellow, White, Black", "Black, Yellow, White", "White, Yellow, Black", "White, Yellow, Black");
        this.addQuestion(q11);
        Question q12 = new Question("Which of the following state flags does NOT have the crescent and star?", "Terengganu", "Melaka", "Negeri Sembilan", "Johor", "Negeri Sembilan");
        this.addQuestion(q12);
        Question q13 = new Question("Which state's flag was claimed to be too simple and dull in 2006?", "Terengganu", "Pahang", "Perlis", "Kedah", "Terengganu");
        this.addQuestion(q13);
        Question q14 = new Question("How many shades of blue are seen on the flag of Sabah?", "3", "4", "1", "2", "3");
        this.addQuestion(q14);
        Question q15 = new Question("What year was the current flag of Sabah adopted?", "1981", "1983", "1986", "1988", "1988");
        this.addQuestion(q15);
        Question q16 = new Question("How many colours are featured on the flag of Malacca?", "2", "4", "3", "5", "4");
        this.addQuestion(q16);
        Question q17 = new Question("Selangor's first flag in the 1780s looked remarkably similar to the flag of which European country?", "Spain", "Germany", "Netherlands", "Ukraine", "Spain");
        this.addQuestion(q17);
        Question q18 = new Question("If you invert the flag of Ukraine, which state would resemble that flag?", "Perak", "Perlis", "Pahang", "Federal Territory", "Perlis");
        this.addQuestion(q18);
        Question q19 = new Question("The dominant colour of Kedah is red. What does the red symbolize?", "Wealth", "Blood shed", "Prosperity", "Agility", "Prosperity");
        this.addQuestion(q19);
        Question q20 = new Question("Which of the following state flags is considered tri-coloured?", "Perlis", "Perak", "Pahang", "Terengganu", "Perak");
        this.addQuestion(q20);
        Question q21 = new Question("What type of blue is used for the Mount Kinabalu silhouette in the flag of Sabah?", "Royal", "Navy", "Zircon", "Icicle", "Royal");
        this.addQuestion(q21);
// END
    }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldV, int newV) {
// Drop older table if existed
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_QUEST);
// Create tables again
        onCreate(db);
    }
    // Adding new question
    public void addQuestion(Question quest) {
// SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_QUES, quest.getQUESTION());
        values.put(KEY_ANSWER, quest.getANSWER());
        values.put(KEY_OPTA, quest.getOPTA());
        values.put(KEY_OPTB, quest.getOPTB());
        values.put(KEY_OPTC, quest.getOPTC());
        values.put(KEY_OPTD, quest.getOPTD());
// Inserting Row
        dbase.insert(TABLE_QUEST, null, values);
    }
    public List<Question> getAllQuestions() {
        List<Question> quesList = new ArrayList<Question>();
// Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_QUEST + " ORDER BY RANDOM()";
        dbase = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = dbase.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
// looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Question quest = new Question();
                quest.setID(cursor.getInt(0));
                quest.setQUESTION(cursor.getString(1));
                quest.setANSWER(cursor.getString(2));
                quest.setOPTA(cursor.getString(3));
                quest.setOPTB(cursor.getString(4));
                quest.setOPTC(cursor.getString(5));
                quest.setOPTD(cursor.getString(6));
                quesList.add(quest);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
// return quest list
        return quesList;
    }
}
```

Here is the Question.java file:

```
package com.example.darel.geogame;

import android.app.Activity;

public class Question extends Activity {
    private int ID;
    private String QUESTION;
    private String OPTA;
    private String OPTB;
    private String OPTC;
    private String OPTD;
    private String ANSWER;
    public Question() {
        ID = 0;
        QUESTION = "";
        OPTA = "";
        OPTB = "";
        OPTC = "";
        OPTD = "";
        ANSWER = "";
    }
    public Question(String qUESTION, String oPTA, String oPTB, String oPTC, String oPTD,
                    String aNSWER) {
        QUESTION = qUESTION;
        OPTA = oPTA;
        OPTB = oPTB;
        OPTC = oPTC;
        OPTD = oPTD;
        ANSWER = aNSWER;
    }
    public int getID() {
        return ID;
    }
    public String getQUESTION() {
        return QUESTION;
    }
    public String getOPTA() {
        return OPTA;
    }
    public String getOPTB() {
        return OPTB;
    }
    public String getOPTC() {
        return OPTC;
    }
    public String getOPTD() {
        return OPTD;
    }
    public String getANSWER() {
        return ANSWER;
    }
    public void setID(int id) {
        ID = id;
    }
    public void setQUESTION(String qUESTION) {
        QUESTION = qUESTION;
    }
    public void setOPTA(String oPTA) {
        OPTA = oPTA;
    }
    public void setOPTB(String oPTB) {
        OPTB = oPTB;
    }
    public void setOPTC(String oPTC) {
        OPTC = oPTC;
    }
    public void setOPTD(String oPTD) {
        OPTD = oPTD;
    }
    public void setANSWER(String aNSWER) {
        ANSWER = aNSWER;
    }
}
```

QuestionActivity.java

```
package com.example.darel.geogame;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;


public class QuestionActivity extends Activity {
    List<Question> quesList;
    int score = 0;
    int qid = 0;
    Question currentQ;
    TextView txtQuestion, times, scored;
    Button button1, button2, button3, button4;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        FlagDatabase db = new FlagDatabase(this); // my question bank class
        quesList = db.getAllQuestions(); // this will fetch all quetonall questions
        currentQ = quesList.get(qid); // the current question
        txtQuestion = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtQuestion);
        times = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timers);
        times.setText("");
// the textview in which the question will be displayed
// the three buttons,
// the idea is to set the text of three buttons with the options from question bank
        button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        button4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
// the textview in which score will be displayed
        scored = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score);

// method which will set the things up for our game
        setQuestionView();
// button click listeners
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
// passing the button text to other method
// to check whether the anser is correct or not
// same for all three buttons
                getAnswer(button1.getText().toString());
            }
        });
        button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getAnswer(button2.getText().toString());
            }
        });
        button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getAnswer(button3.getText().toString());
            }
        });
        button4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getAnswer(button4.getText().toString());
            }
        });
    }
    public void getAnswer(String AnswerString) {
        if (currentQ.getANSWER().equals(AnswerString)) {
// if conditions matches increase the int (score) by 1
// and set the text of the score view
            score++;
            scored.setText("Score : " + score);
        }
        if (qid < 10) {
// if questions are not over then do this
            currentQ = quesList.get(qid);
            setQuestionView();
        }
        else {
// if over do this
            Intent intent = new Intent(QuestionActivity.this,
                    ResultActivity.class);
            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putInt("score", score); // Your score
            intent.putExtras(b); // Put your score to your next
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    }

    private void setQuestionView() {
// the method which will put all things together
        txtQuestion.setText(currentQ.getQUESTION());
        button1.setText(currentQ.getOPTA());
        button2.setText(currentQ.getOPTB());
        button3.setText(currentQ.getOPTC());
        button4.setText(currentQ.getOPTD());
        qid++;
    }
}
```

And here is the xml file for the design interface:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/relatively"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#d15400"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.90"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:background="@drawable/interface12">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout11"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.20"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="1" >
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/score"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Score : 0"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="25.0sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/timers"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="00:00:49"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="25.0sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">



        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout12"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.60"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="1" >
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.40" >
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtQuestion"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="15*2*1-1"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="20.0sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.20"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:weightSum="1" >
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button1"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="80dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:background="#fff821"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="30"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="20.0sp" />
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button2"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="80dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:background="#fff821"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="29"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="20.0sp" />
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button3"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="80dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:background="#fff821"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="32"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="20.0sp" />
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button4"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="80dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:background="#fff821"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="32"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="20.0sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use "blob" to store image.

```
  byte[] data = getBitmapAsByteArray(img);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a column in the database called 'img_link' for example. This column will contain the URL for the image (if it's an online image) or the drawable file name (if the images are included in your Android application), then, you can simply load the content of the image (using the value of that column) in the ImageView associated to each one of your quiz questions.